# What reference documents exist for LLM inference engines and models?

Tags: large-language-models, models, inference

For example, vllm is an inference engine, and according to their roadmap they will incororate vllm into several LLM API engines such as openllm, rayserve, and nvidia triton.

- What are examples of other inference engines?
- You can run the same model (e.g. llama2) under several inference engines.  What is the specification/doc/etc that the inference engine authors would use to implement this?
- What specifications/documentation/etc are used when inference engine authors write an engine to support these models?